# Deploying a community to a scratch org error

Tags: community, salesforcedx, scratch-org

I've been given a task to get familiar with SFDX and working with metadata. Currently have a sandbox org with a couple of flows, a community, various custom objects, etc.. that I'm pulling the metadata from. With that metadata I'm attempting to spin up a scratch org and push the metadata to the scratch then verify that it has the same functionality as the original sandbox.

Running this statement to push the code to my default scratch org

`sfdx force:source:push --json --loglevel fatal -f`

Below is the information that Salesforce is sending back when it fails to perform the deployment:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "error": "Something is wrong with the ba137447-3d4c-4f6d-a90e-5c9823c29a37 in HR_Burn_Pit_Registry1/views/articleDetail.json. Check the value and try again.",
      "fullName": "HR_Burn_Pit_Registry1",
      "type": "ExperienceBundle",
      "filePath": "force-app/main/default/experiences/HR_Burn_Pit_Registry1.site-meta.xml",
      "problemType": "Error"
    }
  ],
  "name": "DeployFailed",
  "message": "Push failed.",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "SourcePushCommand",
  "data": [
    {
      "error": "Something is wrong with the ba137447-3d4c-4f6d-a90e-5c9823c29a37 in HR_Burn_Pit_Registry1/views/articleDetail.json. Check the value and try again.",
      "fullName": "HR_Burn_Pit_Registry1",
      "type": "ExperienceBundle",
      "filePath": "force-app/main/default/experiences/HR_Burn_Pit_Registry1.site-meta.xml",
      "problemType": "Error"
    }
  ],
  "stack": "DeployFailed: Push failed.
    at MetadataRegistry.initializeMetadataTypeInfos.then.then.catch.e (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourceApiCommand.js:63:31)\n    at tryCatcher (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:695:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/****/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)",
  "warnings": []
}
```

Trying to figure out/understand the error message that I got back, 'Something is wrong with the...' Tried reaching out to a few people I work with, and no one is sure what this means, the message isn't very informative.

Here's the code for the component which is causing the error.

```
{
      "componentAttributes" : {
        "numberOfItems" : 5,
        "showViewCounts" : true,
        "title" : "Related Articles"
      },
      "componentName" : "selfService:similarArticles42",
      "id" : "ba137447-3d4c-4f6d-a90e-5c9823c29a37",
      "renderPriority" : "NEUTRAL",
      "renditionMap" : { },
      "type" : "component"
    }
```

Hopefully this is enough information, any suggestions or direction would be helpful. I'll update or respond if more information is needed.

Comment: can you confirm if you have added                                        
   "experienceBundleSettings": {
       "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }                                                                                                                                    
    in your project-scratch-def.json file

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. The project scratch def does have those settings enabled.

Comment: If I remove the referenced view and it's corresponding route, I get the same error for another view. Once cleaning up that second view and route, I get the following error message:

"error": "Your community needs a route with route type list-701. Update your file and try again.",

Comment: @JasonFisher not sure if it will help, but the list-701 is in the following files
/views/campaignList.json
/routes/campaignList.json
Make sure you have those files.
Note that SF experienceBundle have a lot of bugs from my experience. I found out you can put the  force-app/main/default/experiences in the .forceignore, then push (make sure you have the siteDotComSites metadata in the repo). If the push success ignore the siteDotComSites (switch between both metadata types) and push again - it should fix most of your issues if not all.

Comment: I think it will take time until the experienceBundle will be a real enterprise grade feature, try to take an existing source with several communities and push to a scratch org - good luck with that :)